# When I run the program, the output is "inf"

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    
int main() {
    float sum = 0;
    int n;
    cout << "Nhap gia tri n = ";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        sum += 1 * 1.0f / i;
    }
    cout << "Tong la: " << sum << endl;        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What should the output be, instead of "inf?"

Comment: Style trick: my vietnamese skill is absolute 0. In your current code is it not a problem, but if you post more complex code, I suggest to translate everything in English. Also string constants help others to understand your code.

Comment: Is ∞ is not enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start your loop by `i==0`. In the C++ floating point, `1/0==inf`. After that, it does not matter, what you add to it, because inf + anything is inf.

You probably want to start your code with `i=1`.

In your case, I would also filter out the `n<1` inputs, it will result 0. Just exit with an error message like *Cáa duu vao nho hon 1 hoac khong phai so nguyen khong hop le*.